# Using a try-catch within a property?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, nullreferenceexception

The following code just doesn't work like it should:

```
get
{
    try
    {
        foreach (object o in NullObjectList)
        {
            if (o.Property)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException) {}

    return false;
}
```

Why does Visual Studio pause and break when it attempts to iterate over the NullObjectList? Usually it just catches the exception and moves on. What is unique about this?

**Edit:** An alternate solution is to just check if the object is null, but I am still curious as to why the try-catch doesn't work in this scenario.

Comment: You should never catch `NullReferenceException`. Instead, just check to see if the object is null.

Comment: I don't think that's possible in my code, but I'll look into it. Edit - yes, okay. But I am still curious about this for future reference.

Comment: Just check `if (o != null && o.Property)`

Comment: && o.Property != null too?

Comment: BTW: don't use exception handling for normal control flow.

Comment: @MitchWheat +1. However I'd like to add WHY not. Firstly exception handling is slow, like 100s of clock cycles slow. Secondly during debugging its annoying. I typically have VS set to break on exception. This really helps to track down errors early on (before they propagate out of the scope of the problem).

Answer (score 1):

It works as expected for me, Visual Studio does not break when the exception is raised and the exception is properly caught. Are you sure you don't have the "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" set to thrown in the Exception Dialog?
I tried in Visual Studio 2008 and 2012.